# DateFormat gives ParseException: Unparsable date error

Tags: java

I am trying to parse by date:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

This is the error I am getting:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-04-28 04"

Comment: wheres the minutes?

Comment: The format you provided does not match the input `2013-04-28 04`.

Comment: as stated in the comments above, you can try with the input : `2013-04-28 04:00` and notice the `:00` for minutes

Comment: You'd need to change `MMM` to `MM` as well... oh, and switch the day/year around. Basically, hardly *anything* in your format string matches what's in the value.

Comment: @meJustAndrew The month format doesn't match either, `MMM` is Jan, Feb, Mar etc.

Comment: @1615903 you are right, didn't even noticed. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

The date "2013-04-28 04" is in the form `yyyy-MM-dd HH`

which does not match the format `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm`

You'd want something like "28-Apr-2013 04:00"

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat()) is some documentation of `SimpleDateFormat` and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html) about `ParseException`